Python Floating-Point Arithmetic comparison
I don't really understand why this comparison will still evaluate False even though they are exactly the same.
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
getcontext().prec = 10 

x1 = 1.1 
x2 = 1.0
print( 0.1*(abs(x2 - x1)) == 0.01) ## evaluates to False. But they are mathematically equal. 
print(0.1*(abs(x2 - x1)))
print(round(Decimal(0.1)*Decimal(abs(x2 - x1)),2) == 0.01) ## evaluates to False still
print(round(Decimal(0.1)*Decimal(abs(x2 - x1)),2))
print(0.01)

How else can I manipulate it such that it compares correctly?

This question appears to boil down to "why is Decimal('0.01') == 0.01 false?"

If you asked that question, instead of overcomplicating it as you have done here, you might get an answer.

"...even though they are exactly the same." Do you understand why there is no binary floating point value that is exactly equal to "0.01?" If not, then you might want to read this famous paper: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/103162.103163

Decimal(0.1) The entire purpose of the Decimal class is so that you can use an exact string representation of a number, such as Decimal("0.1").  But you have not done that, you have just used a regular imprecise float value 0.1, so you've already lost.

If you need exact decimal fractions, that you can compare for exact equality, and that never show any "weird" roundoff errors, then the Decimal class is probably what you want.  But that's certainly an "if", and using the Decimal class is at least a little bit more complicated than not using it.  If you got "weird" roundoff errors, and someone told you "Just use Decimal", they may have done you a disservice.  In most work involving fractional numbers, roundoff error is inevitable, so it's better to learn how to work around it (like, by not expecting or comparing for exact equality).

@SolomonSlow That's an excellent paper, of course, but do you honestly think that J. Random Programmer (no offense to Justin, here) is going to be able to read it and immediately resolve any confusion they might have about floating point?

Thanks for the useful notes and info, will give it a curious read. I published the whole code fragment because I was worried it might have been due to any intrinsic properties of Python's round() method which affects the arithmetic.
Can I check if it would be better to wrap the rounding-error into a str() and decimal() for subsequent comparison or if these might serve better? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/how-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python

@SteveSummit, IDK. I think I learned a lot from it when I first read it. But I already had been employed as a developer for about ten years by then,* and while I did not know much about floating point at that time, I guess at least I knew not to use them for currency and not to test them for exactly equality. I guess I had not yet stopped to wonder why it was OK to use my pocket calculator for currency,  but not doubles in C.

* Promoted from "J. Random Programmer" to Joe Average Software Engineer.

Decimal(0.1)

This does first create float (with all its' limitations w.r.t precision) and then convert it to Decimal instance, use string representation to avoid that, consider that
from decimal import Decimal
print(Decimal(0.1)+Decimal(0.1)+Decimal(0.1)==Decimal(0.3))  # False
print(Decimal("0.1")+Decimal("0.1")+Decimal("0.1")==Decimal("0.3"))  # True


Thanks for pointing that out, can I check how this would work with rounding error values? I presume it would still be able to convert the floating-point value (up to the default 11 d.p.) as a string and wrap that into a Decimal() object for comparison? Maybe I would add a round() to substitute as a tolerance since I would only be concerned up to 3 d.p., so Decimal(str(round(a,3))), where a is some floating-point, i.e., 5.2421214111?
